# Helm chart-testing: define Kubernetes Secret required for chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am writing a Helm Chart which references a Kuberentes Secret in its template. Something like the following in `deployment.yaml`:

```yaml
            - name: SUPERTOKENS_API_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: supertokens-secret
                  key: supertokens-api-key
```

Now I want to use [Helm chart-testing](https://github.com/helm/chart-testing) repo with `ct install` to test the chart in a kind cluster only started for this test.
It fails, because the cluster itself does not contain the secret `supertokens-secret`.

How can I tell chart-testing to create a specific set of secrets before running the installation test?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I tell chart-testing to create a specific set of secrets before running the installation test?

You can add a secret manifest in `/templates` for his helm chart, so it will create one during the installation/testing of your helm chart.

Also:
If your only goal is to make sure the chart works, you might want to just comment that part of the manifest for the time of testing, or point to it any other existing secret.

Comment: Commenting will not be an option, since the test is also part of the CI setup, which is the gatekeeper for merge requests.

Comment: I now used the option to add an additional "test_secret.yaml" in the templates, and an additional variable in values `createTestSecrets` which is used to disable this file. Only if set to true the test secrets are generated. But this is a quite ugly solution, since it pollutes the "production" values with test variables.

Comment: It sounds like the automated test you have to pass may be improved tbh. You either have to use a dirty way (like mentioned),  adjust them to allow this case of a non-existing secret, or comment this section and decide it is good enough if tests are passed like this (probably disable some branch protection to merge)